# Does theory of general relativity work for anti matter?

Tags: general-relativity

Einstein's theory of general relativity put forward the concept of the space manifold theory. According to this ,all masses create depressions in the manifold which causes matter to attract each other. But when anti matter(not yet discovered)
and matter are thought to repel each other.Then, will anti matter form hills? How can that theory explain that?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance That should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

> Then, will anti matter form hills?

No. The gravitational interaction between particles and their antiparticles is thought to be governed by the contribution of these entities to the stress-energy tensor and, as such, thought *always* to be *attractive*, whether particle interacts with anti particle or anti particles mutually interact. I don't believe, though, that anyone has made enough positrons or other anti particles to test this proposition experimentally.